# 18.04: Need to update to GTK 3.24

Tags: apt, gtk3, glib

I need to update my GTK version from 3.20 to 3.24 to build a package from source.

Running

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-0
```

gives me.

```
libgtk-3-0 is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu4).
```

I tried building it from source, which results in the same problem for glib. Which in turn told me my meson version is to old, when I tried to build that from source. At that point I realized that there must be a better way.

Is there a way to install a sufficiently new version of GTK with apt (or any other tool for that matter)?
It seems that there is a version for [Debian Sid](https://launchpad.net/debian/sid/+source/gtk+3.0).

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and therefor apt is set to the bionic repository.

Comment: As @Gryu mentions below it's available for eoan/19.10, but by adding those packages to your system you'll cause much of your system to become 19.10 with it's coming EOL.  You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to view the status of your packages/system as it stands now, however you'll see a very markedly different result in `ubuntu-support-status` once you start adding packages intended for another release (19.10 reaches EOL in a few months so it's packages will) so be aware of the security risks if you don't use VM/fully-upgrade..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg --list | grep libgtk` on 19.10 shows:

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64                                            3.24.12-1ubuntu1                     amd64        GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin                                                3.24.12-1ubuntu1                     amd64        programs for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-common                                             3.24.12-1ubuntu1                     all          common files for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64                                           2.24.32-4ubuntu1                     amd64        GTK graphical user interface library - old version
ii  libgtk2.0-bin                                               2.24.32-4ubuntu1                     amd64        programs for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-cil                                               2.12.40-2                            amd64        CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
ii  libgtk2.0-cil-dev                                           2.12.40-2                            amd64        CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
ii  libgtk2.0-common                                            2.24.32-4ubuntu1                     all          common files for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-dev:amd64                                         2.24.32-4ubuntu1                     amd64        development files for the GTK library
ii  libgtk2.0-doc                                               2.24.32-4ubuntu1                     all          documentation for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk3-perl                                                0.036-1                              all          Perl bindings for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtkd-3-0                                                 3.9.0-1                              amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library - D bindings
ii  libgtkglext1:amd64                                          1.2.0-9                              amd64        OpenGL Extension to GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64                                      1:2.24.5-4                           amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ 2 (shared libraries)
ii  libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64                                      3.24.1-1                             amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtksourceview-4-0:amd64                                  4.4.0-1                              amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview-4-common                                   4.4.0-1                              all          common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtkspell0:amd64                                          2.0.16-1.2                           amd64        spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView widget
```

So you could try to install it using eoan's repositories, but it is better to use 19.10 somewhere on VM to avoid dependencies brokenness and a lot of issues by using this bad workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So maybe I'll just update to 19.10 then. If I decided to use eoan's repo would I do that by adding it to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: You could encounter some issues after upgrade. So I would recommend to make a bootable usb flash drive and try it first by choosing: Try without installing. Make sure, there's no issues with wi-fi, display and so on first.